# How can autoimmunity be selective?

Tags: immunology, autoimmune

Vitiligo is a skin disorder where the pigment disappears. [More on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitiligo) This is believed to be caused by autoimmunity and has made me interested in autoimmunity in general.  I am still very much a layman, however.

One of the characteristics of vitiligo is that it is uneven. Some patches of skin look normal, others are completely albino-like.

**If the immune system has decided that skin pigment is an enemy, why doesn't it destroy *all* the skin pigment?**

I understand that little is known about vitiligo, so I will accept answers describing similar effects in other autoimmune disorders.

Comment: Your supposition is incorrect, the immune system does not destroy pigment